# C++ - Program exhibits strange behavior when attempting to connect on TCP clients to addresses that don't exist

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-studio-2015, tcp, network-programming

Working on a project in Visual Studio 2015 with a configurable amount of TCP connections to different clients.  Noticing strange behavior when run on representative hardware setups with closed networks.

Assuming each of the TCP connections is pointing to a valid other address, the program functions perfectly, sending and receiving messages as necessary to all the different clients.  However, if I unplug one of the machines, the server starts to chug.  The most obvious sign (though not the only issue caused by this) is one of our UDP sockets which should receive messages at 10hz starts receiving at approximately 1hz.  This will continue until you re-connect the missing computer to the network.  Strangely, at this point, the telltale UDP socket mentioned earlier will quickly receive and handle all of the messages it should have been receiving during the downtime.  After this, the program will function normally again.

I'm at home thinking about this so I don't have source code to post (and would probably be frowned on for doing this anyway), but I'm not familiar with reasons that an invalid TCP connection would cause behavior like this.  Anyone experience anything similarly and have something that worked for them in this situation?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Is there a part of the code in C++ where you think the problem arises? If not, this is more of a networking question and doesn't belong on StackOverflow. It's also a very broad question, meaning that arriving at useful answer is very difficult.

Comment: Connect() to a non-existent address can take up to 60 seconds to return.

Comment: I'll investigate how long between the various Connect attempts and their resolutions and update if this doesn't help.  Thanks!

Comment: Does your code handle the errors that result from the unplugging correctly? Or does it perhaps enter a pathological spin loop?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the UDP messages are not being sent at the normal rate when you are trying to connect to a TCP socket suggests that you are  using the same thread for both actions.

> Aside: I promise that those "AWOL" UDP messages have not been sent.  UDP messages don't linger around in the network waiting to be delivered.

If the thread issuing the TCP connect request is the same thread that is pushing the UDP messages then you've found your problem.   You need to allow for the fact that a blocking TCP connect request can block the thread for a long time.  Solutions include using a non-blocking connect request, or firing up separate threads for TCP and UDP.  Which approach works best depends on your design.

[Consider using ASIO, it provides a good tool for handling non-blocking I/O. but it probably requires a significant redesign of your application.]

Unfortunately, this is just guessing.  We need to see at least some of the code involved to provide a definitive answer.